# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ‘exports’ of object ‘

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there is lots of question with this title in SO and other forums but none of them solve my problem (I'm not sure doing them correctly) . I want to use canvasjs to draw canvas. Also I'm working with react and new in it. Structure of my react project is as below:

```
+node_modules
+public
+src
  -canvas.min.js
  -canvas.react.js
  -App.js
  -index.js
  -indes.css
-package.json
```

my App.js file contain these codes:

```
    /* App.js */
import React from 'react';
import CanvasJS from './canvasjs.min';
var CanvasJSReact = require('./canvasjs.react');
var Component = React.Component;
var CanvasJS = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJS;
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;


class App extends Component {   
  render() {
    const options = {
      title: {
        text: "Basic Column Chart in React"
      },
      data: [{              
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "Apple",  y: 10  },
                    { label: "Orange", y: 15  },
                    { label: "Banana", y: 25  },
                    { label: "Mango",  y: 30  },
                    { label: "Grape",  y: 28  }
                ]
       }]
   }

   return (
      <div>
        <CanvasJSChart options = {options}
            /* onRef = {ref => this.chart = ref} */
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
//module.exports = App;                              
export default App;
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

when i run `npm start` in cmd this error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ‘exports’ of object ‘
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to export an extended `Component` without importing `Component` from React. Trying changing your import statement to `import React, {Component} from 'react'`

Answer (score 1):

if your canvasjs is a ES6 module then you should use

```
import CanvasJS from './canvasjs.min';
```

if its a simple commonjs or umd module use

```
var CanvasJS = require('./canvasjs.min');
```